# QGIS Zonal Statistics returns empty

Tags: qgis, raster, zonal-statistics

I am using QGIS 3.18 to do a quick calculation of the population inside a buffered area. The data for the population comes from WorldPop, the file I got is in the form of GeoTIFF. I inserted it as a raster layer. Then, I put some point type geometries in the map and created a 100 km buffer around the point.

I run the Zonal Statistics tool,
The Zonal Statistics then created a new layer, with the categories (sum, mean, etc). But the fields are returned empty (null).

The funny thing is if I do this in QGIS 3.10, the zonal statistics works. Exactly the same settings. The only difference, the stats (sum) is entered directly as a column in the buffer layer, and it contains data. Is this a known bug?

Comment: What about the CRS of the raster and the vector layer before you start the Zonal Statistics? Are both in the same projection?

Comment: Yes. I checked and rechecked all CRS. Project, Point, and Raster are in the same CRS. I even, counterintuitively, tried it on different CRS (just to test), also doesn't work.

Comment: Check the band of the raster you are using for this tool.

Answer (score 0):

Check your CRS.

This tool require a Projected CRS.

WGS84 doesn't work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try "Raster statistics for polygons" from Saga tools. It work's fine.